# Why does tf.memory show such different memory usage than the Chrome task manager?

Tags: google-chrome, tensorflow.js

tf.memory() shows

```
{unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 8454208, numTensors: 149, numDataBuffers: 149, numBytes: 25457348}
```

The task manager shows almost 1000 times more as a memory footprint (roughly 8,160,000K)
[image]

TFJS version 1.5.1; Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit); Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

tf.memory shows only the memory allocated to tfjs tensors.

The gpu process is not specific to a single tab nor to a specific script such as tfjs. It is more generic and shows how much memory is consumed by the gpu for accelerating graphic elements. It is noteworthy to indicate that tfjs might incur some overhead for putting code on the gpu which is not output by tf.memory.

To sum up, the gpu process output will be higher than `tf.memory`'s.